# How to recover data from a partially overwritten partition

Tags: raid, data-recovery

By mistake, I configured a 900GB partition to be part of a 50GB raid. The sync is complete and my understanding is that only the first 50GB of the bigger partition is overwritten. How do I recover the rest of the data?

When I try to mount this partition by identifying it as ext3, it mounts only the 50GB overwritten space.

This partition was earlier divided into various logical volumes(all ext3 filesystems) through LVM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: With the partition being divided into different volumes in some unknown fashion, you're going to have an even rougher time than normal recovering any data that hasn't been overwritten.  I have to agree with @BrentPasbst .  If you don't have backups, you've lost your data.  Make peace with that and move on.

Comment: If this is critical data STOP accessing the drive NOW.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like at this point you may need to use a forensic recovery tool or a data recovery firm to get the data back out.  Or recover from your backup files, but it sounds like you don't have any.